# How to insert multiple JSON rows into a T-SQL table

Tags: c#, json, t-sql, cross-apply

I am trying to insert following JSON document into T-SQL:

```
  {
    "GLDETAIL": {
      "RECORDNO": "264378-1756289-919567--accrual",
      "BATCH_DATE": "02/01/2022"
    }
  },
  {
    "GLDETAIL": {
      "RECORDNO": "264378-1756290-919568--accrual",
      "BATCH_DATE": "02/01/2022"
    }
  }
,
  {
    "GLDETAIL": {
      "RECORDNO": "264379-1756291-919569--accrual",
      "BATCH_DATE": "02/01/2022"
    }
  },
  {
    "GLDETAIL": {
      "RECORDNO": "264379-1756292-919570--accrual",
      "BATCH_DATE": "02/01/2022"
    }
  }
,
```

This is T-SQL stored procedure that I was trying to fix, but only it inserted one row instead of four.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertPerfCounterData1]

@json NVARCHAR(max)

AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO dbo.PerfCounter2 (
  [RECORDNO]
 ,[BATCH_DATE]

)
SELECT
    RECORDNO,
    BATCH_DATE
    
FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (@json)

WITH (

    RECORDNO     VARCHAR(MAX) '$.GLDETAIL.RECORDNO',
    BATCH_DATE   DATETIME2(7) '$.GLDETAIL.BATCH_DATE'
) AS jsonValues

END
```

This is result inside table.

```
RECORDNO                        BATCH_DATE
264378-1756289-919567--accrual  2022-02-01 00:00:00.0000000
```

I believe it is something to do with where it has "CROSS APPLY and OPENJSON", but I am not sure how to fix it.

**Update**:

I got this error after I applied the new SQL script that Larnu provided below:

[image]

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character ']' 
 is found at position 501.
  Source=Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider
```

This is C# code:

```
     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sprocname, conn))
                {
                    // Set command object as a stored procedure
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    // Add parameter that will be passed to stored procedure
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(paramName, paramValue));

                cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your JSON has multiple root nodes, and so SQL Server is only picking up the first. We can see this with the following:

```sql
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = N'{
    "GLDETAIL": {
      "RECORDNO": "264378-1756289-919567--accrual",
      "BATCH_DATE": "02/01/2022"
    }
  },
  {
    "GLDETAIL": {
      "RECORDNO": "264378-1756290-919568--accrual",
      "BATCH_DATE": "02/01/2022"
    }
  }';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
```

Notice only one set is picked up, for GLDETAIL, not 2.

We can "fix" this by making the data inside an array:

```sql
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = N'{
    "GLDETAIL": {
      "RECORDNO": "264378-1756289-919567--accrual",
      "BATCH_DATE": "02/01/2022"
    }
  },
  {
    "GLDETAIL": {
      "RECORDNO": "264378-1756290-919568--accrual",
      "BATCH_DATE": "02/01/2022"
    }
  }
,
  {
    "GLDETAIL": {
      "RECORDNO": "264379-1756291-919569--accrual",
      "BATCH_DATE": "02/01/2022"
    }
  },
  {
    "GLDETAIL": {
      "RECORDNO": "264379-1756292-919570--accrual",
      "BATCH_DATE": "02/01/2022"
    }
  }';

SELECT GLD.RECORDNO,
       GLD.BATCH_DATE
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[',@JSON,']')) OJ
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(OJ.[value],'$.GLDETAIL')
                  WITH (RECORDNO varchar(30),--USe an appropriate length, not MAX
                        BATCH_DATE date) GLD;
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your SQL script, but on my C# solution file, I got an error as shown on the top.

Comment: Do I have to take care of 'N' if I use current stored procedure? It seems like some type of CONCAT issue.

Comment: The above works, which suggests that the JSON in the question isn't representative of your real JSON, @Java. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c14fb5d9412771e3f21d6265b7e186e7)

Comment: Yes, the example data set works, but when it goes thru VS solution, I am getting an error. Any idea? I would like to get some idea regards to the error message I am getting. Thanks.

Comment: I also added the C# code (on the above) that use for reference. This is where I got the code: https://chris.koester.io/index.php/2018/03/21/load-json-into-sql-server-using-a-stored-procedure-and-csharp/

Answer (score 1):

Before editing your post, the problem would solved by putting the Json in "[ ]".
And I think you even  don't need  `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (@JSON)`. The Query will be like this:

```sql
    DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) =  N'
    {"GLDETAIL": {"RECORDNO": "264378-1756289-919567--accrual", "BATCH_DATE": "02/01/2022"}},
    {"GLDETAIL": {"RECORDNO": "264378-1756290-919568--accrual", "BATCH_DATE": "02/01/2022"}},
    {"GLDETAIL": {"RECORDNO": "264379-1756291-919569--accrual", "BATCH_DATE": "02/01/2022"}},
    {"GLDETAIL": {"RECORDNO": "264379-1756292-919570--accrual", "BATCH_DATE": "02/01/2022"}}';
    
    INSERT INTO dbo.PerfCounter2 (
      [RECORDNO]
     ,[BATCH_DATE]
    )
    
    SELECT RECORDNO, BATCH_DATE
    FROM OPENJSON((CONCAT('[',@JSON,']'))) 
    --CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (@JSON)
    WITH (
        RECORDNO     VARCHAR(30) '$.GLDETAIL.RECORDNO', --Use also an appropriate length, not MAX 
        BATCH_DATE   DATETIME2(7) '$.GLDETAIL.BATCH_DATE'
    ) AS jsonValues
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. The issue now is on C# code that I cannot delete period at the end of output. This is latest development of this issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72073896/c-sharp-how-to-format-json-file-with-a-comma-between-each-output-but-no-comma-a)